# Свёрточная нейронная сеть

Tags: javascript, нейронные-сети

В общем, как это работает?

Изображение из Википедии гласит, что изначальный набор данных анализируется и уменьшается с каждым слоем, в конце чего мы получаем один слой вывода. (надеюсь, я правильно описал). 
[image: Архитектура свёрточной нейронной сети]

И что изображено на картинке?

Мы берём слой `28*28` и берём с него только матрицу `5*5`, по ней строим новый слой `24*24` и снова берём матрицу `5*5`, и так до последнего слоя с ответом?

Так, а как это создать?

По сути смысл такой сети — это создание большого количества нейронных сетей равному количеству слоёв, верно? Каждая следующая анализирует вывод предыдущей и передаёт его дальше, пока не достигнем ответа. Или это совершенно не так, и такой аппарат нейронной сети обычно интегрирован в популярные библиотеки?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Постепенно отвечая на все ваши вопросы.

> И что изображено на картинке?

Забудьте про эту картинку. Это самое непонятное объяснение принципа работы СНС, которое я когда либо видел. Вообще, советую не смотреть на картинки, я лично смог понять их принцип работы только на видео. [Вот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmpDIaiMIeA), кстати, самое лучшее пошаговое объяснение (если не знаете английский, включите субтитры).

> Мы берем слой 28*28 и берем с него только матрицу 5*5, по ней строим новый слой 24*24 и снова берем матрицу 5*5 и так до последнего слоя с ответом?

Не совсем так. Мы берем матрицы размера NxN (обычно не больше 8 и не обязательно квадратные), которые называются фильтры. Обрабатываем наше изображение с помощью этих фильтров. На выходе получиться фотография но уже немного видоизмененная (вся суть того как работают фильтры). Делаем мы это несколько раз. Сколько, зависит от того как глубоко мы хотим уйти. Иными словами, для каждой задачи свое значение.

> Так а как это создать?

Не нужно создавать велосипед. Используйте уже готовые библиотеки. Со свёрточными сетями очень хорошо работает [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/). Вот [здесь](http://tflearn.org/) можно очень быстро научиться им пользоваться.

> По сути смысл такой сети это создание большого количества нейронных сетей равному количеству слоев, верно?

Нет. По сути здесь 2 НС - свёрточная и в самом конце сеть прямого распространения. А суть здесь заключается в том, чтобы "свернуть" фото путем последовательного применения различных фильтров. Чем дальше слой тем абстрактнее фильтр.

В любом случае, советую сначала посмотреть видео о котором я говорил, а потом уже вам станет намного понятнее то о чем я здесь написал.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Видео действительно хорошо все обьяснило. Но теперь вопрос в практике. Я понимаю что нужно создавать фильтры, выбирать размер окна и количество слоев, но это все нужно делать вручную или обычно это предусмотрено библиотекой? К тому же я очень хочу что бы это было в знакомой мне среде, так что я наверное буду использовать JS библиотеку: http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/

Comment: Конечно, лучше использовать ту библиотеку язык которой уже знаете/. А на счет фильтров и слоев это такие вещи которые называются гиперпараметры. Их нужно выбирать вручную. В интернете можно найти очень много задач и как их люди решали. Посмотрите какие гиперпараметры использовали они и отталкивайтесь от этого. С опытом научитесь сразу подбирать правильные значения. Удачи!

Comment: Большое спасибо. Подробно и понятно :)

Comment: Рад что смог помочь)

Comment: кстати, что до обёрток над низкоуровневыми бекендами - почему бы не keras?