# Какую нейронную сеть выбрать для решения задачи

Tags: opencv, нейронные-сети, распознавание, машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект

Недавно начал изучать нейронные сети. Как оказалось, существует огромное количество разнообразных видов нейронных сетей. Я не в состоянии выбрать одну из них самостоятельно, поэтому я прошу помощи здесь. Какая нейронная сеть мне нужна?

Задача примерно такая: на входе дается изображение, на котором находится четыре других изображения одинаковых размеров. Они все стоят в одной линии, как в примере ниже.

[image: Пример]

Между ними может быть расстояние, а может и не быть. Фон также может быть любой другой.

Имеется директория со всеми возможными изображениями (~50 шт), которые могут быть найдены на входном изображении. Примерно так выглядит директория:

[image: Директория]

На выходе нужно получить имена файлов, изображения которых совпадают с найденными. То есть, если вкратце, на входном изображении нужно найти четыре изображения из директории и вернуть имена найденных изображений. Во входных данных, на изображениях, которые нужно распознать, могут быть небольшие помехи в виде надписи в углу или по центру.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если действительно всего 50 семплов и других никогда не будет - лучше обойтись без НС.

Comment: @vp_arth Может быть в будущем до 100, но не более. Чем тогда пользоваться?

Comment: Нейронные сети предназначены для работы с неизвестными входными данными(например, распознать махаона), у вас же входные данные вот они. Можно решить алгоритмически. Вычисляете центры изображений и сравниваете окрестности, например.

Comment: К тому же вы всегда можете особым образом пометить свои изображения(типа стеганографии) =)

Comment: @vp_arth За центры изображений спасибо, попробую так. Что значит пометить изображения? Можно чуть подробнее?

Comment: Самое простое - использовать младшие биты каждого байта изображения, чёт/нечет. В вашем случае, достаточно придумать какие-то сигнатуры и заполнить ими картинку. Потом при чтении узнаёте сигнатуру, сопоставляете. Как из пистолета по уткам на Денди в детстве =)

Comment: @vp_arth Не совсем понял. Как заполнить картинку сигнатурами? Изображение на входе - это скриншот, и этот скриншот будет обновляться каждые пару секунд. Если имеется ввиду вручную, то это не вариант.

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ, возможно он вам подойдет лучше так как он более универсален.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если работа с изображениями, то однозначно [OpenCV](http://opencv.org). 
Модуль нейросетей там один из многих, это и понятно - изображение необходимо правильно подготовить прежде чем НС на него набижит, очень вероятно что и без НС решится задача (в основном так и происходит). 
Тем не менее, в версиях 3.1 и 3.2 модулю нейросети уделено было некоторое внимание, можно надеяться и на дальнейшее развитие.

Что касается вашей задачи, то НС точно не нужна. Если нужно найти картинки, которые в точности совпадут - вычислите и сравните суммы (или средние) цветов пикселей по строками или по столбцам. 
Если не в точности - нужно искать и сравнивать контуры (findContours).
Если нужно одну картинку найти в другой - поиск по образцу (templateMatching). 
Продолжить можно примерно до завтрашнего обеда :-)

Comment: Сможет ли findContours найти контуры изображения, если оно не прямоугольное, а в форме ромба, например?

Comment: Он вам очертания бабочки найдёт) [Рыбка внизу](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)

Comment: @Newbie, если бы findContours искал только прямоугольники, его бы назвали findRectangles :-) Изображение в виде ромба не может быть, но может быть фигура в изображении в виде ромба. Чтобы выявить эту фигуру, нужно чтобы у нее были очертаемые края, края в свою очередь можно выявить множеством способов - Canny, Laplacian, threshold, цветовой фильтр, и пр. 
Для Вашей задачи обратите внимание на templateMatching - есть много примеров - например http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

Comment: я уже недавно рекомендовал здесь - прекрасные видеоуроки по выявлению объектов, на OpenCV - https://www.intorobotics.com/how-to-detect-and-track-object-with-opencv/

Comment: @EugeneBartosh Уже пытался использовать template matching, но все его методы постоянно находят не то изображение, которое нужно. Попробую еще, спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста. В opencv почти всё критически зависит от подбора параметров - нужно точно понимать какой за что отвечает, часто приходится экспериментировать с подбором значений.

Comment: еще обратите внимание на feature detection / matching - http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html 
Свои особенности есть, сразу не получится, если будут вопросы то пишите

Comment: Я не могу понять только, как в моем случае поступить. Допустим, я итерирую все изображения из директории как шаблон и буду искать их на входном изображении. Но ведь при случае, когда шаблон не находится, все равно показывается другая область, которая нашлась, хоть она и неверная. В голову приходит только вариант с извлечением каждого найденного элемента и сравнением его с изображением из директории (проверка на дубликаты). Или можно как-то по другому?

Comment: Ну я бы на вашем месте так сделал - сканировать каждый раз изображения плохо (их же и 500 может быть), надо при вводе темплейта выделить точки и дескрипторы и сохранить это в базе (формат нужно разработать). 
Затем при поиске из анализируемого изображения также 1 раз извлекаются точки и дескрипторы, и поочередно сравниваются с точками/дескрипторами в базе - выбрать лучший результат и проверить на мин. критерий (не менее X точек например).

Comment: кроме сравнения точек можно также сравнивать насколько совпадает взаимное их расположение - на этом основан алгоритм Bag Of Words - тоже рекомендую, используется в OCR (в OpenCV есть реализация)

Comment: Очень странный у вас подход к НС.

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно не очевидный ответ от *@Eugene Bartosh*. Когда стоит задача в том, чтобы распознать изображения есть один очень простой ответ - **Сверточная нейронная сеть**. Это самый оптимальный вариант, который будет работать во всех случаях. И когда я читаю комментарии из разряда НС здесь будет не совсем полезна или лучшее вообще ее не использовать, то меня это очень сильно удивляет. По большей части такие "советчики" не знают НС, потому что нет такой задачи где НС была бы бесполезной и ненужной. Да в некоторых случая НС может быть overkill но зато вы не будете основываться на ручном сравнении пекселей и прочих аспектах которые тут же сломаются если задача хоть чуть чуть измениться (иными словами масштабируемость). НC же без разницы в каких координатах находиться иображение и какого оно размера и абсолютно точно **НЕ НУЖНО** готовить изображение к обработке. Вы просто подаете НС фото и Если там есть то что мы ищем, НС ее просто найдет и вам не нужно беспокоиться о том, как она это сделает, главное ее обучить этому. Все что нужно знать о сверточных НС можно прочитать из моего ответа на этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614251/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C/614338#614338).

Comment: То, что было описано вами по ссылке и реализовано в библиотеке TensorFlow, является примитивной разновидностью алгоритмов LBP и HAAR. "Уровень" распознавания можно оценить по их демовидео - даже распознавание лица не показали... высококонтрастные надписи крупным планом... ну как-то ну совсем не впечатляет... API 10 функций... зато всё "просто" и не надо ничего готовить :-))

Comment: Если выбросить из вашего ответа критику соседнего ответа другого участника (что не стоит  постить как ответ) - то останется "Сверточная нейронная сеть. Все что нужно знать о сверточных НС можно прочитать из моего ответа на этот вопрос.". Это не является полноценным ответом.

Comment: "какого оно размера" - угу, ведь входные данные могут быть любого размера. И да - они вроде всё же чувствительны к масштабировнию,не?

Comment: таки да :-))))))