# Какой метод распознавания актуален для распознавания рукописных букв (кириллица)?

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, распознавание-образов, распознавание-символов

Если стоит задача в распознавании **рукописных букв**, то какой метод/алгоритм машинного обучения наиболее актуален и даёт более точные результаты в этой сфере на текущий момент? К примеру, лучше использовать нейронные сети, или можно вполне обойтись методами машинного обучения без ИНС?

Сейчас передо мной стоит задача распознавания рукописных букв (кириллица). Буквы будут распознаваться по отдельности (не слова целиком). На вход буду подавать таблицы с различным рукописным написанием букв русского алфавита. Нужна помощь в избрании наиболее оптимального алгоритма/метода для распознавания рукописных символов.

Comment: По-моему сейчас большинство пользуется сверточными нейронными сетями (Convolutional Neural Networks) для подобных задач.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда речь идет о распознавании изображений то сразу возникает ответ - Сверточная нейронная сеть. Ваш случай тому не исключение. Сразу скажу что существует много готовых решений с уже готовой архитектурой НС, поэтому самому писать ничего не нужно. Если C++ или Python, советую [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/). Чтобы понять как работают Сверточные НС, почитайте мой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614251/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C/614338#614338) на похожий вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

Не нужно никаких нейронных сетей, тем более свёрточных.
Берите [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr), тренируйте на почерк и используйте.
Сам Tesseract использует НС, но не свёрточную :-)

---

Совсем недавно сделал проект - используется Tesseract для выявления charboxes, затем Tesseract пытается распознать то что выявил, параллельно эти же charboxes пытается распознать алгоритм на базе [OpenCV kNN](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d8/d4b/tutorial_py_knn_opencv.html).

Для того, что не распознано, есть GUI, в котором можно выделить charbox и указать вручную что это за символ. В результате формируются данные для тренинга tesseract (то что он не смог сам распознать и было введено вручную), и данные для тренинга kNN (то что tesseract распознал и то что вручную введено). 
После >10 тренировок на символ он начинает довольно устойчиво распознаваться обеими системами.