# Как подавать на НС данные разных видов

Tags: сеть, нейронные-сети, типы-данных, теория

Добрый день. Скажите пожалуйста, каким образом люди загружают в нейронную сеть например  изображения, массивы текстовых данных, подборки результатов каких нибудь игр, ведь в теории основная особенность НС в том, что в них все входные и выходные параметры представлены в виде чисел с плавающей точкой обычно в диапазоне [0..1]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого перед загрузкой данных в НС они проходят процесс **нормализации**.

Почти все данные можно представить в формате 0..1 или же -1..1. В самых простых случаях будет использоваться функция minmax `norm = (input - min) / (max - min)`. Также можно использовать softmax (если знаете английский [вот](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-intuition-behind-SoftMax-function/answer/Sebastian-Raschka-1?srid=u1fbk) отличное обьяснение).

Изображения обрабатываются сверточными НС и там нет ограничений на входные данные и там мы представлям изображение в виде двумерного массива пикселей и подаем на вход нс значение каждого пикселя. Подробнее о сверточных НС можно прочитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614251/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C/614338#614338).

Текст тоже обрабатывается по болшьей части сверточными нейронными сетями и там довольно сложная система представления данных. Об этом лучше почитать отдельно вот [здесь](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/).

Данные игр тоже можно представить в виде определенных наборов параметров. Вот [пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjOEHvzv15s) НС которая предсказывает победу той или иной команды в MOBA игре основываясь на статистических данных.

И вообще чтобы понять всю картину советую прочесть две моих статьи: [раз](https://habrahabr.ru/post/312450/) и [два](https://habrahabr.ru/post/313216/).

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ, кстати изучение НС я как раз начал с ваших статей (так как понятно и не сложно), но там к сожалению у вас НС обычного типа, а вот про свёрточные сети не чего (буду надеяться на продолжение ), поэтому я так и туплю с ними. Я хотел ещё у вас спросить как уравновешивать весы в свёрточной сети ? И как тренировать НС при помощи Генетического Алгоритма (в пару слов)?

Comment: Рад что вам понравились мои статьи. В пару слов конечно очень тяжело это объяснить но я постараюсь. В сверточных сетях мы не нормализуем входные данные. На вход подаются значения пикселей 0..255. Их этих значений получается 2D карта из пикселей по которой потом мы проходимся выбранным фильтров. Эти фильтром мы обрабатываем каждый участок фото и на выходе получаем слегка измененную картину. И так далее пока мы не сможем "свернуть фото" в очень маленькую карту и следом разложить ее в одномерный массив чтобы пропустить через обычную СПР. Оперировать большими значениями нам позволяет функция ReLU.

Comment: Чтобы лучше понять CNN посмотрите видео в моем ответе, там все очень понятно расписано. А что на счет ГА то можно представить это как фабрику по производству и скрещиванию созданных ею НС. Допустим ГА создает 100 НС и отправляет их на решение задачи. После того как все завершили решение задачи ГА берет НС с лучшими результатами и скрещивает их. Это дает потомство которое сможет решить проблему еще лучше. Это повторяется пока не будет достигнут желаемый результат. Скрещивание происходит как в биологии, мы берем несколько весов одного родителя и другого и строим из них другую НС.